# Find documents having a field greater than the length of an embeded array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is a group schema:

```js
GroupSchema{
    membersLimit: Number,
    listOfStudents: [String]
}
```

I want to find all the groups where the number of students is less than `membersLimit`.

I tried the folliowing query

```js
await Group.find({
    membersLimit: { $gt: 'listOfStudents'.length },
})
```

This query returns documents having students less than 14 i.e. length of `listOfStudents`.

I also tried this

```js
await Group.find({
    listOfStudents: { $size: { $lt: 'membersLimit' } },
})
```

This query returns the following error

```
error The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

  assert.ok(!isNaN(val))
```

Is there a way to do this with single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$expr`, to compare the array size and the field, like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      "$membersLimit",
      {
        "$size": "$listOfStudents"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ce6eHX2odDq).